# vuejs replace part of string in the template with a variable from the data method

Tags: vue.js

I want to replace a hardcoded printers route in my template with a variable named route found in the data method:

I have 
`@click="$router.push('/printers')"`

and I have data:

```
data() {
    return {
        data: {},
        dataReady: false,
        route: 'printers'
    }
},
```

I thought I could do

`@click="$router.push('/{{route}}')"`

But I was mistaken.

Any ideas how to get route into the string?

Comment: try `@click="$router.push('/' + this.route )"`

Comment: didn't know I had access to this, unfortunately it comes up as undefined

Comment: ooh but `@click="$router.push('/' + route )"` worked.... thanks!